# PostgreSQL and SSRS: Passing parameters to PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, reporting-services

I tried to use postgreSQL stored function in ssrs, firstly tried using like this :

```
select * 
from reports.get_daily_cash_flow_test('01.01.2017'::timestamp with time zone, 
'01.01.2019'::timestamp with time zone, True, Offset)
WHERE Offset = @Offset
```

It causes syntax error, near `@Offset`. `@Offset` is integer type variable, added in Parameters, and also added in dataset parameters (also tried using query like :

```
select * 
from reports.get_daily_cash_flow_test('01.01.2017'::timestamp with time zone, 
'01.01.2019'::timestamp with time zone, True, @Offset)
```

Just because `@Offset` is already added in dataset parameters but still syntax error.

After that I tried using function as stored procedure. Still the problem is that my function returns Table, and in dataset parameters it requires me to add output parameters (returned table columns) values.

After that tried using simple query without stored function which looks like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (l.player_id))
FROM public.logins l
WHERE (l.login_date between @DateFrom AND @DateTo)
```

Error message is

*An error occurred while executing the query.
ERROR [42703] ERROR: column "datefrom" does not exist;
Error while executing the query*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I found the solution, once executing query you should use it like :

`SELECT * FROM reports.get_devices(?,?,?)`

question marks instead of parameters, that does the trick.