# Cannot use Named Parameters with SSRS and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, reporting-services

I'm trying to add named parameters to a dataset query in a SSRS report (I'm using Report Builder), but I have had no luck discovering the correct syntax.  I have tried @parameter, $1, $parameter and others, all without success.  I suspect the syntax is just different for PostgreSQL versus normal SQL.

The only success I have had with passing parameters was based on [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54415418/postgresql-and-ssrs-passing-parameters-to-postgresql-function)

It involves using ? for every single parameter.

My query might look something like this:

`SELECT address, code, remarks FROM table_1 WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND apt_num IS NULL AND ADDRESS = ?`

This does work, but in the case of a query where I pass the same parameter to more than one part of the SELECT statement, I have to add the same parameter to the list multiple times as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyO9H.png).  They are passed in this order, so adding a new parameter to an existing query results in having to reshuffle, and sometimes completely rebuild, the query parameters tab.

What are the proper syntax and naming requirements for adding named Parameters when using a PostgreSQL data source in SSRS?

Comment: Create a CTE at the top of the query of the form `with inparms as ( select ? as from_date, ? as to_date, ? as address)` and then `cross join inparms` into your main query.  If need be, you can cast the `?` placeholders to the correct PostgreSQL types.  Let me know if you need an example.

Answer (score 1):

From my comment, this is what it would look like with a regular join:

```
with inparms as (
  select ? as from_date, ? as to_date, ? as address
)
select t.address, t.code, t.remarks 
  from inparms i
       join table_1 t
         on t.date between i.from_date and i.to_date
        and t.apt_num is null
        and t.address = i.address;
```

I said `cross join` in my comment because it is sometimes quicker when retrofitting somebody else's SQL instead of trying to untangle things (thinking of a friend who uses `right join` sometimes just to ruin my day).

Comment: It looks like your solution still requires them to be named ? in the parameters tab like in my image above, but it greatly improves the readability of the main select statement by allowing you to sub in the names you've set in inparms.  With your solution, the order of the parameters in that tab only comes into play when defining your inparms as well.  This is great, because adding a new "where" that uses a new parameter required a bunch of busywork before and now you just add it to the end of your parameters tab and also the end of your inparms and use it anywhere in the statement.  Thanks!

Comment: @Bellingsam  I assumed you have no choice but to use `?` as the bind parameters in the SQL queries.  I have used SSRS only once--about six years ago--and that was more than enough for me to never use that steaming pile of garbage ever again.